# PHP counter button on click function

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<?php
    $chance=$_COOKIE['chanceNo'];
    ?>
        <input length="2" type="text" name="chance" id="chance" readonly="readonly" value="<? echo $chance?>"/>
```

I am trying to create an onlick function to decrease the number of chances. Like for example, when user click a card/button, $chance in textbox should decrease. How can i go about it?

Comment: do you want change in cookie too ?

Comment: Erm, yeah, coz, i need the cookies to be updated into database as well..

Comment: you need to do more, on click of button, call ajax, read cookie value, decrement and set in cookie again. hope that will work :)

Comment: PHP is serverside, so you'll need JS to.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in 2 ways

- one by adding a form and a button with onclick event, and on each click submit the form with javascript to the same page, decrease the cookie value in php and display the page.
- Another one using AJAX if you dont want to reload the page. You can use a separate file where you decrease the cookie value and send the reduced cookie value in ajax response. You can fill the text box with the ajax response value.

Hope this helps.